# In iOS, what is the difference between the Magnetic Field values from the Core Location and Core Motion frameworks?

Tags: ios, core-location, core-motion, magnetometer

I have two ways of getting the magnetic fields (strength, x, y, and z) using the iOS device's magnetometer.

1) Core Location
Used the CLHeading from `CLLocationManagerDelegate` method `locationManager:didUpdateHeading:`. This is similar to Apple's Teslameter sample app.

2) Core Motion
Used `CMMagneticField` from `CMMotionManager`'s `magnetometerData.magneticField`.

Questions:
a) What is the difference between the two? I am getting different values from both. I was expecting that they will return the same values.
The difference is most notable when I start the app from a resting position (face up in a table), and then lift the device up in to the air.
b) If there is a difference, when should I use the magnetic field from Core Location heading, and when should I use the magnetic field from Core Motion?

Note: I also am not sure if the "magnetic field" of Core Location and Core Motion refer to different magnetic field concepts.
Note: I computed strength as the square root of (x^2 + y^2 + z^2) for both approaches.

Comment: Are you using the `magneticHeading` property of the `CLHeading`?

Comment: @ThomasW No sir, I'm using CLHeading's x, y, and z.

Answer (score 196, accepted):

To unravel this I've spent a bit too much time digging through the Apple docs.

There are three ways of obtaining magnetometer data

1/ [Core Motion framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion)
CMMotionManagers's [`CMMagnetometer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmmagnetometerdata) class

2/ Core Motion framework
[CMDeviceMotion](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmdevicemotion) `CMCalibratedMagneticField` property

3 / [Core Location framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocation)
CLLocationManager's `CLHeading`

1/  supplies 'raw' data from the magnetometer.
2/ and 3/ return 'derived' data. The  numbers in both cases are similar (though not exactly the same).

**Difference between Core Motion's CMMagnetometer and CMCalibratedMagneticField**

1/ and 2/ - both from the Core Motion framework - differ as follows:

CMDeviceMotion Class Reference

```
@property(readonly, nonatomic) CMCalibratedMagneticField magneticField
```

> Discussion
>   The CMCalibratedMagneticField returned by this property gives you the total magnetic field in the device’s vicinity without device bias. Unlike the magneticField property of the CMMagnetometer class, these values reflect the earth’s magnetic field plus surrounding fields, minus device bias.

CMMagnetometer gives us raw data, CMCalibratedMagneticField is adjusted data.

**Difference between Core Motion's CMCalibratedMagneticField and Core Location's CLHeading**

The docs are not immediately clear on the difference between 2/ and 3/, but they do generate different numbers so let's do some digging….

**Core Location framework**
**CLHeading**

From [Location Awareness Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/GettingHeadings/GettingHeadings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH5-SW1)

> Getting Heading-Related Events
>
> Heading events are available to apps running on a device that contains a magnetometer. A magnetometer measures nearby magnetic fields emanating from the Earth and uses them to determine the precise orientation of the device. Although a magnetometer can be affected by local magnetic fields, such as those emanating from fixed magnets found in audio speakers, motors, and many other types of electronic devices, Core Location is smart enough to filter out fields that move with the device.

Here are the relevant `CLHeading` 'raw' properties

```
@property(readonly, nonatomic) CLHeadingComponentValue x
@property(readonly, nonatomic) CLHeadingComponentValue y
@property(readonly, nonatomic) CLHeadingComponentValue z
```

> The geomagnetic data (measured in microteslas) for the [x|y|z]-axis. (read-only)
>       This value represents the [x|y|z]-axis deviation from the magnetic field lines being tracked by the device.
>       (*older versions of the docs add:*) The value reported by this property is normalized to the range -128 to +128.

I am not clear how a microtesla measurement can be 'normalized' (compressed? clipped?) to a range of +/-128 and still represent the unit it claims to measure. Perhaps that's why the sentence was removed from the docs. The units on an iPad mini do seem to conform to this kind of range, but the iPhone4S gives *CMMagnetometer* readings in higher ranges, eg 200-500.

The API clearly expects you to use the derived properties:

```
@property(readonly, nonatomic) CLLocationDirection magneticHeading
@property(readonly, nonatomic) CLLocationDirection trueHeading
```

which give stable N/S E/W compass readings in degrees (0 = North, 180 = South etc). For the true heading, other Core Location services are required (geolocation) to obtain the deviation of magnetic from true north.

Here is a snippet from the `CLHeading` header file

```
/*
 *  CLHeading
 *  
 *  Discussion:
 *    Represents a vector pointing to magnetic North constructed from 
 *    axis component values x, y, and z. An accuracy of the heading 
 *    calculation is also provided along with timestamp information.
 *  
 *  x|y|z
 *  Discussion:
 *    Returns a raw value for the geomagnetism measured in the [x|y|z]-axis.
```

**Core Motion framework**
 **CMDeviceMotion**  **CMCalibratedMagneticField**

```
/*
 *  magneticField
 *  
 *  Discussion:
 *          Returns the magnetic field vector with respect to the device for devices with a magnetometer.
 *          Note that this is the total magnetic field in the device's vicinity without device
 *          bias (Earth's magnetic field plus surrounding fields, without device bias),
 *          unlike CMMagnetometerData magneticField.
 */
@property(readonly, nonatomic) CMCalibratedMagneticField magneticField NS_AVAILABLE(NA,5_0);
```

**CMMagnetometer**

```
 *  magneticField
 *  
 *  Discussion:
 *    Returns the magnetic field measured by the magnetometer. Note
 *        that this is the total magnetic field observed by the device which
 *        is equal to the Earth's geomagnetic field plus bias introduced
 *        from the device itself and its surroundings.
 */
@property(readonly, nonatomic) CMMagneticField magneticField;
```

*CMMagneticField*
This is the struct that holds the vector.
It's the same for `CMDeviceMotion`'s calibrated magnetic field and `CMMagnetometer`'s uncalibrated version:

```
/*  CMMagneticField - used in 
 *  CMDeviceMotion.magneticField.field
 *  CMMagnetometerData.magneticField
 *  
 *  Discussion:
 *    A structure containing 3-axis magnetometer data.
 *
 *  Fields:
 *    x:
 *      X-axis magnetic field in microteslas.
 *    y:
 *      Y-axis magnetic field in microteslas.
 *    z:
 *      Z-axis magnetic field in microteslas.
```

---

The difference between 2/ and 3/ are hinted at here:

Core Location *CLHeading*

> Represents a vector pointing to magnetic North constructed from axis component values x, y, and z
>
> Core Location is smart enough to *filter out fields that move with the device*

Core Motion  *CMCalibratedMagneticField*

> [represents] Earth's magnetic field *plus surrounding fields*, without device bias

So - according to the docs -  we have:

1/ *CMMagnetometer*
Raw readings from the magnetometer

2/ *CMDeviceMotion (CMCalibratedMagneticField*) magneticField*
Magnetometer readings corrected for device bias (onboard magnetic fields)

3/ *CLHeading [x|y|z]*
Magnetometer readings corrected for device bias and filtered to eliminate local external magnetic fields (as detected by device movement - if the field moves with the device, ignore it; otherwise measure it)

**Testing the theory**

[image]

I have put a [Magnet-O-Meter demo app on gitHub](https://github.com/foundry/MagnetoMeter) which displays some of these differences. It's quite revealing to wave a magnet around your device when the app is running and watching how the various APIs react:

*CMMagnetometer* doesn't react much to anything unless you pull a rare earth magnet up close. The onboard magnetic fields seem far more significant than local external fields or the earth's magnetic field. On my iPhone 4S it consistently points to the bottom left of the device; on the iPad mini it points usually to the top right.

*CLHeading.[x|y|z]*  is the most vulnerable (responsive) to local external fields, whether moving or static relative to the device.

(CMDevice)*CMCalibratedMagneticField* is the most steady in the face of varying external fields, but otherwise tracks it's Core Location counterpart *CLHeading.[x|y|z]* pretty closely.

*CLHeading.magneticHeading* - Apple's recommendation for magnetic compass reading -  is far more stable than any of these. It is using data from the other sensors to stabilise the magnetometer data. But you don't get a raw breakdown of x,y,z

```
             influenced by
             onboard fields    local external fields   earth's field
yellow               X                   X                 X
green                _                   X                 X
blue                 _                   _                 X
red                  _                   _                 X
```

yellow *CMMagnetometer*
 green *CLHeading.[x|y|z]*
 blue *CMCalibratedMagneticField*
 red *CLHeading.magneticHeading*

This does seem to contradict the docs, which suggest that *CLHeading.[x|y|z]* should be less influenced by local external fields than *CMCalibratedMagneticField*.

What approach should you take? Based on my limited testing, I would suggest…
*If you want a compass reading*
CLHeading's `magneticHeading` and `trueHeading` will give you the most accurate and most stable compass reading.
*If you need to avoid Core Location*
CMDeviceMotion's `CMCalibratedMagneticField` seems to be the next most desirable, although considerably less stable and accurate than `magneticHeading`.
*If you are interested in local magnetic fields*
CLHeading's 'raw' x y and z properties seem to be more sensitive to local magnetic fields.
*If you want all of the  data including onboard magnetic fields*
Raw magnetometer data from CMMagnetometer. There is really not much point using this unless you are prepared to do tons of filtering, as it is hugely influenced by magnetic fields generated on the device itself.

Comment: Will there be a difference in values if CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXMagneticNorthZVertical is changed, say, to CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXTrueNorthZVertical? If yes, why did you choose CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXMagneticNorthZVertical?

Comment: @MiuMiu, it won't make any difference as the reference frame only affects CMAttitude (roll,pitch,yaw etc) - which I am not using in this demo.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Since I am interested in local magnetic fields, I will proceed with using CLHeading's raw x, y, and z values.

Comment: @foundry, I suppose you mixed up crosses for green and blue at the second column of your table, because green is CLHeading.[x|y|z] and it's not influenced by local magnetic disturbances

Comment: @AlexSmirnov - I have just checked my code and green is definitely CLHeading. In _theory_ this one shouldn't be affected by local magnetc fileds. But just try waving a magnet around the device while running the app. Green responds, blue does not. This suprised me also (one of the reasons for the long reply).

Comment: @foundry I must first appreciate this answer. I have been given a task to "Execute a piece of code when a human is near to the iPhone/iPad (without using any camera or face detection)" I come across your article and seems very interesting to do this using the magnetometer, I studied about magnetic field and the sensors and the Motion sensors in the iPhone/iPad. 
And then I read term Biomagnetism (Magnetic Fields Produced by the Human Body) can iPhone/iPad's magnetometer are powerful enough to detect the Biomagnetism, Like a Human heart produce a mag...(TO BE CONTINUED ON NEXT COMMENT...)

Comment: Like a Human heart produce a magnetic field of about ~500,000 FemtoTesla even human Skeletal Muscle movement produce a magnetic field of about ~50,000 FemtoTesla (1 million times weaker than Earth’s field)
My question is can we detect such body’s incredibly tiny natural magnetic fields via the iPad/iPhone's Magnetometer.

Comment: I don't usually post Thanks! comments but this has to be one of the best answers I've ever seen on Stack Overflow (and I've seen tens of thousands on many tags); it's hard to find good information on this topic and your answer's coverage of this topic is incredibly valuable. I wish Apple hired people like you to write their documentation. If I had the rep I'd give you a large bounty for this.

Answer (score 1):

this answer is based on my interpretation of the documentation links below

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLHeading_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CLHeading

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMagnetometerData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CMMagnetometerData

a) CLHeading is "**deviation** from the magnetic field lines being tracked by the device" while magnetometerData.magneticField "is the **total magnetic field** observed by the device which is equal to the Earth’s geomagnetic field plus bias introduced from the device itself and its surroundings".

So CLHeading gives you filtered values with the **Frame of Reference** being the existing magnetic field of the earth. While magnetometerData gives you unfiltered values with the **Frame of reference** being the device.

b) if you were doing anything with location where you wanted to know where is magnetic or true north I'd recommend using CLHeading. If you wanted to create an app that responds to magnetic fields in the devices immediate vicinity or you had some specific sensor fusion you wanted to perform maybe try create an AHRS for instance then go with CMMagneticField.

Comment: 1) When should you use CLHeading with regards to magnetic fields? As I understand from your answer, your use of CLHeading is about direction, not magnetic field strength. Or is it the only sensible use?  
2) Can you also tell me why Apple used CLHeading in the Teslamater sample app instead of Core Motion's CMMagneticField?

Comment: @MiuMiu, see my answer - CLHeading does measure field strength, and according to my tests - which contradict the docs on this issue - CLHeading's x|y|z measurements are the most responsive to local external magnetic fields, so would be the best candidate for a general-purpose magnetic field detector.

Answer (score 1):

An important thing to remember when using the CLHeading.[x|y|z] values to calculate the local magnetic field strength is that the CLLocationManagerDelegate method

- (BOOL)locationManagerShouldDisplayHeadingCalibration:(CLLocationManager *)manager

should be set to return YES. I have found that the magnetometer readings are never calibrated if this calibration warning is turned off, and that as a result the calculated field strength is very unstable when the orientation of the device is changed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the magnetometerData.magneticField it telling you the acceleration, not the position (hence why you get large values moving from still to moving) whereas the location manager provides data on the direction the device is pointing in.