# how to get proper x, y, and z value of magnetic field around iOS device ?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ipad-2, magnetometer

I'm trying to get magnetic field value around my iOS device ( iPad 2 ). I have been googling long time about those subjects, but I couldn't find anything that works properly.

i'm trying to make something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJlgDIO3oL8).

i read Apple Documentation about magnetic field how i can get value  there is two framework can help me core motion and core location but in my case i will use core motion to get calibrated magnetic field around my device by using CMDeviceMotion and this Property CMCalibratedMagneticField

> The CMCalibratedMagneticField returned by this property gives you the
>   total magnetic field in the device’s vicinity without device bias.

this code written in SWIFT

```
        let manager = CMMotionManager()
        var valX: Double!
        var valY: Double!
        var valZ: Double!
        var valAccuracy: Int32!
        if manager.deviceMotionAvailable{
            manager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = .1
            manager.startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue()){
                (data: CMDeviceMotion!, error: NSError!) in

                if let isError = error{
                    NSLog("Error: %@", isError)
                }
                valX = data.magneticField.field.x
                valY = data.magneticField.field.y
                valZ = data.magneticField.field.z
                valAccuracy = data.magneticField.accuracy.value


                if values != nil{
                    values!(x: valX, y: valY, z: valZ, accuracy: valAccuracy)
                }

                self.delegate?.getMagneticFieldFromDeviceMotion!(valX, y: valY, z: valZ)
            }

        } else {
            NSLog("Device Motion is not available")
        }
```

When I try to run my application in (IPad 2) it return x, y, z value but it change in crazy way and very fast!! If I move magnetic in x axis also y change!!
I use neodymium magnet, I was very careful when I use it to not allow it harm my device.

Questions:

1. why when i try to move magnet x and y change even i change only x ?
2. i have to do calibration before i start to have accurate value ?
3. i have to to put my device in specific situation to get proper value ?
4. there is any algorithm i have to use to filter x , y and z ?

Comment: For what you're doing I think you'll want CMMagnetometerData rather than the calibrated version. Make sure you look at this very well researched answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15470571/59541

Comment: thanks for answer, i will use x,y and z value of magnetic field around my device to input it to my painter application, i read this topic it's very useful especially when he talk about ( CMCalibratedMagneticField  ) which i use to get magnetic field around device without device bias, but i did not get my answer for my question, i run his application in github but the same problem i mentioned above (  x and y change even i change only x ? ) although i put device in flat surface!! @NateCook