# What is the most accurate way to find north

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, core-motion, compass-geolocation

I am trying to build a compass app on iOS. I have looked around the web, but I am pretty confused which would be the best way.

Right now I am using `CoreLocation`

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading)
{
    trueHeading.text = String(newHeading.trueHeading)
    magneticHeading.text = String(newHeading.magneticHeading)
}
```

But I compared with the compass app on the iPhone and it shows different values sometimes.

Is there a better way to find TRUE north? Using CoreMotion or something like that?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polaris

Comment: After some digging I found this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15470571/4915700 . Contains a lot of info and I believe I will stick to using CLHeading