# why iphone magnetometer results are different from android

Tags: android, ios, iphone, magnetometer

Recently I was working with IOS and Android magnetometer for a project, I searched and found that there exist three ways to get the magnetometer data in IOS (check this question  ["In iOS, what is the difference between the Magnetic Field values from the Core Location and Core Motion frameworks?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15380632/in-ios-what-is-the-difference-between-the-magnetic-field-values-from-the-core-l)).

I tried all the three methods (Core Location,Device Motion and Core Motion) but none of them gets the same results as in android TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD.

Comment: I'ts device motion you should use - so that you get calibrated magnetic field data. Also make sure the android sensor has the right quality.
Open google maps on both devices - compare. I have a newly bought api 28 Android with vastly unsuperior sensor quality to my iPhone 6 device :/